# is it a good idea to have crash/bumper guard on rear of hatch back

Tags: car, supplemental-restraint-system, bumper, rear-end, hatch

Crash guards usually causes problem with Airbag deployment prevents bonnet from acting as crumple zone and impacts the chassis of the car badly which is more harmful for passengers according to this [source](https://auto.hindustantimes.com/auto/news/explained-why-are-bull-bars-and-crash-guards-on-indian-cars-are-banned-41647665655702.html)

In the case of rear of hatch back car , there's no crumple zone such as big boot space and there's no air bag sensor on the behind so having a crash guard does more good than bad.

Can someone share their insights on this please ?

Comment: Please explain what you're asking about.  Every car I have ever owned has had both a front and a rear bumper installed from the factory.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I dispute your premises. One, every vehicle has body structure and sheet metal further back from the location of the rear wheels. This serves as a rear "crumple zone." Whether a specific vehicle is as good as another will depend upon the design of the specific vehicle. Two, airbag sensors react to sudden unexpected acceleration or deceleration of the car body; the sensor's location within the car body is irrelevant. All in all, this seems to ask for discussion, and not opinion. This site seeks questions with declarative answers, not discussions. I voted to close as opinion-based.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica - Thanks for the insight.  But again if car gets hit from the rear and airbag deploys , then it might block the drivers view which is more dangerous and again if car gets hit from rear I don't think the car will experience any kind of deceleration.

Comment: You are incorrect in assuming a hatchback has no crumple zone at the rear.  They do have them.  Also, your assertion that a 'big boot space' is a crumple zone is incorrect.  A boot is not a crumple zone.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Well , that makes sense. But should we avoid having a crash guard at rear just like front ?

Comment: Do you drive in reverse at 60mph? If so, you probably could have bull bars at the rear. Otherwise, why do you think they would be of value?

Comment: @RoryAlsop - During city drive , some vehicle hits the car from behind and this causes damage and even in motor way some trucks lose the balance hits the other vehicles in behind.  so I'm thinking having a steel crash guard at rear might be helpful

Comment: No - it likely won't be helpful. It will likely make a crash better for the vehicle, but worse for the occupants. Personally I'd rather permanently wreck my car than permanently wreck my spine.

Comment: @JamesT - well said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's generally not a good idea.

The manufacturer spends vast amounts of money and development time in building in proper type-approved crash protection. Randomly adding girders will transmit the forces of the impact to different places, potentially making things far worse.